# Why is there so much outdated font info in my PDF (XML) metadata?

Tags: pdf-a, hyperxmp, xmp

I am creating a PFD/A compliant file. I finally managed to set `pdfcreator`, `pdfproducer` and all other fields to my liking (using `hyperref` and `hyperxmp`) and even suppress `PTEX.*` info. All is good.

Except: Checking the file's XMP data, under the namespace `http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/t/pg`, there is `xapTPg:Fonts`, “an unordered array of fonts that are used in the document (including any in contained documents)” according to the docs. Where does this come from? It contains all the fonts I might have used at some point, starting with `Computer Modern`, but there's no trace of them left anywhere in my source files. Deleting all auxiliary files did not help.

I am using LuaLaTeX to compile the .pdf.

**ETA:** Ok, so here's the MWE. I am using the freely available IBM Plex fonts, and [this color profile](http://www.eci.org/_media/downloads/icc_profiles_from_eci/ecirgbv20.zip).

```
% !TeX program  = lualatex
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,twoside]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont[BoldFont={IBMPlexSerif-SemiBold.ttf}]{IBMPlexSerif-Regular.ttf}
    \setsansfont[BoldFont={IBMPlexSans-Medium.ttf}]{IBMPlexSans-Regular.ttf}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}

\usepackage[pdfa]{hyperref}

    \immediate\pdfobj stream attr{/N 3}  file{eciRGB_v2.icc}
    \pdfcatalog{%
        /OutputIntents [ <<
            /Type /OutputIntent
            /S/GTS_PDFA1
            /DestOutputProfile \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R
            /OutputConditionIdentifier (eciRGB v2)
            /Info(eciRGB v2)
        >> ]
    }

\hypersetup{pdftitle={My Title},pdfauthor={Ingmar},pdfproducer={},
pdfcreator={},pdfaconformance={U},pdfapart={2},keeppdfinfo}

\pdfvariable suppressoptionalinfo 15
\pdfvariable omitcidset=1

\begin{document}

\chapter{Problemaufriss}

Nicht als öffentliche Sachen sind dagegen Sachen zu verstehen, die bloß mit einer 
Legalservitut belastet sind, wie dies zB beim Betreten des Waldes als 
Duldungspflicht des Waldeigentümers (§ 33 Abs 1 ForstG), bei der sog 
„Wegefreiheit im Bergland“ (zB § 1 Abs 1 sbg WegefreiheitsG, § 47 Abs 1 oö 
TourismusG), bei der luftfahrtrechtlichen Überflugsbefugnis (§ 2 LFG) oder auch 
bei speziellen Duldungspflichten (zB § 72 WRG) der Fall 
ist.\!\footnote{\textsc{Raschauer}, AllgVerwR\textsuperscript{3} (2009), Rz 1\,424.}

\end{document}
```

Link to the [PDF is here](https://www.docdroid.net/plxQwZq/comply-pdf). It compiles, it validates as PDF/A, but I have this in my data:

[image]

Comment: you should really know by now, that one need a test file to check this.

Comment: Right. Let me whip one up real quick.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I amended my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hyperxmp is quite eager to add all info it can get to the metadata. And here it gets all fonts *declared* in the document (and not only the used fonts).

You can disable the whole font section with

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\hyxmp@xmptpg@schema}{%
  \ifLuaTeX
    %\luadirect{write_xmp_font_list(\the\hyxmp@cct)}% disable this
  \fi
  \hyxmp@add@simple{xmpTPg:NPages}{\@pdfnumpages}%
}
\makeatother
```

But imho it would be good if this were optional and more specific to the actually embedded fonts.

Comment: I couldn't agree more, and will suggest as much to Scott Pakin, the maintainer. Thanks for clearing up this mystery for me.